# Inserting into python dictionary without quotes

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

First of all. Thank you to anybody who can help me hear. I am a python beginner but having searched high and low I cannot seem to find the answer, so I am reluctantly posting for help. I am trying to build an API request in Python. I have followed a tutorial and I can make it work using a fixed value however I need to switch the "metrics" out for my own which is a list around 200 long and not sequential.

A working example is as follows:

```
body = {
'rsid': 'vrs_xxx_abgglobalvrs',
 'globalFilters': [
        {
            'type': 'dateRange',
            'dateRange': '2022-01-05T00:00:00.000/2022-02-04T00:00:00.000'
        }
    ],
    'metricContainer': {
    'metrics': [{
                "columnId": "0",
                "id": "metrics/event13"
            },
            {
                "columnId": "1",
                "id": "metrics/event23" 
            },
            {
                'columnId': '2',
                'id': 'metrics/event149'
            }

]
    },
    'dimension': 'variables/daterangeday',
    'settings': {
        'countRepeatInstances': 'true',
        'limit': 50,
        'page': 0,
        'dimensionSort': 'asc'
    }
}
```

If you print this the results show as the following:

```
....0/2022-02-04T00:00:00.000'}], 'metricContainer': {'metrics': [{'columnId': '0', 'id': 'metrics/event1'}, {'columnId': '1', 'id': 'metrics/event2'}, {'columnId': '2', 'id': 'metrics/event45'}]}, 'dimension': 'variabl...
```

However when I use create my dynamic code an update the body dictionary I get the an extra quote at the start and end of my dynamic value:

```
....0/2022-02-04T00:00:00.000'}], 'metricContainer': {'metrics': [**"**{'columnId':'0','id': 'metrics/event1'},{'columnId': '1','id':......
```

For reference this dynamic value (string) is created by using a list of events generated in the following way:

```
list_of_events = df['id'].tolist()
list_of_cleaned_event = []
metricstring = ""
columnId = 0
strcolumn = str(columnId)
for events in list_of_events[0:3]:
    metric = str("{'columnId': '"+strcolumn+"','id': '"+events+"'},")
    columnId += 1
    strcolumn = str(columnId)
    list_of_cleaned_event.append(metric)

for i in list_of_cleaned_event:
   metricstring=metricstring+i
final = (metricstring[:-1])
```

and the body looks like this:

```
body = {
'rsid': 'vrs_avisbu0_abgglobalvrs',
 'globalFilters': [
        {
            'type': 'dateRange',
            'dateRange': '2022-01-05T00:00:00.000/2022-02-04T00:00:00.000'
        }
    ],
    'metricContainer': {
    'metrics': [final]
    },
    'dimension': 'variables/daterangeday',
    'settings': {
        'countRepeatInstances': 'true',
        'limit': 50,
        'page': 0,
        'dimensionSort': 'asc'
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem here? Is it this line `str("{'columnId': '"+strcolumn+"','id': '"+events+"'},")`

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
final = []

list_of_events = ["metrics/event13", "metrics/event20", "metrics/event25"]
for columnId, events in enumerate(list_of_events[0:3]):
    metric = {'columnID': str(columnId), 'id': events}
    final.append(metric)
```

Define body as below

```
body = {
'rsid': 'vrs_avisbu0_abgglobalvrs',
 'globalFilters': [
        {
            'type': 'dateRange',
            'dateRange': '2022-01-05T00:00:00.000/2022-02-04T00:00:00.000'
        }
    ],
    'metricContainer': {
    'metrics': final
    },
    'dimension': 'variables/daterangeday',
    'settings': {
        'countRepeatInstances': 'true',
        'limit': 50,
        'page': 0,
        'dimensionSort': 'asc'
    }
}
```